# Android RTSP stream from IP camera without delay

Tags: android, rtsp, ip-camera

I need to stream rtsp-video from IP camera in local network to my android app. It's very easy to use VideoView and play it as url, or SurfaceView and play stream on it with native MediaPlayer. But when I stream that way - I've recieved a 6-second delay when my phone is buffering that video. As I read, there is no way to change buffer size of MediaPlayer. But I saw several apps that stream video from my camera in almost real-time. I've read a lot about this - cause I'm not the first one who encountered this problem - but didn't find any useful info.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vlc-android, it works well to play my cameras' rtsp links:

https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk#get-it-via-maven-central

The delay is about 1 second.